# Remote WebSphere MQ Configuration with multiple consumers

Tags: distribution, ibm-mq, mq

we have a situation where, we already have a working setup with a vendor that sends us messages over a remote queue. We have only one consumer today that consumes these messages from the queue.

We would like to add another consumer on our side, to consume the same message. Our goal is to achieve this without impacting the vendor that is sending us the messages (or may be least possible impact.).

In this situation,can you please help suggest how the new configuration (using distribution list on our side possibly) would look like. Can this be achieved without the vendor having to do any changes on their side.

Current configuration is simple. The transmission Q has been setup on the vendor side (under their Q MGR) that sends it to the MCA sender - which in turn is received by the MCA receiver on our side that puts it in the final destination Q. This is where we are looking to make the change to be able to be received by second consumer.

**Update:**

Hi Rob, thanks for the answer. To be on the same page. Here is the current topology.

```
Vendor Side Producer --> Proxy QA inside Q Mgr MAGR1 --> 
Sender MCA (with a channel defined) --> (Over the Internet) --> (Receiver MCA) --> 
QA inside Q Mgr MAGR2 --> Consumer.
```

You suggestion is we do this ..

```
Vendor Side Producer --> Proxy QA inside Q Mgr MAGR1 -->
Sender MCA (with a channel defined) --> (Over the Internet) --> (Receiver MCA) --> 
NEW_TOPIC inside Q Mgr MAGR2 --> 
Two subscribers before the Two queues QA.1 and QA.2 --> to two consumers.
```

Can you please elaborate what is Sub1 and Sub2?

Just trying to make sure that there is no code to be written on our side. Also no code changes on vendor side. Just that the channel on vendor side needs to be bounced. We are on the receiving side. Again appreciate your feedback. I am going to take this as a recommendation to the MQ team on Monday.

Rob thanks a lot - really appreciate your help.
One last question. I can see that we are changing the original QA into a type topic now.
Do you think there is no change to vendor code (whether MQ code / JMS code) to reflect that.

Comment: Please add the brand of message queue system you're using, the answer will be quite product-specific.

Comment: Its IBM MQ. Sorry I forgot to mention it in the original question. Also, I am not sure if the vendor is using the JMS API or the traditional MQ API. We are trying not to ask vendor to change code or configuration to deliver a message to a NEW distribution list on our side (unless thats the last option). THanks for you help / recommendation.

Comment: I modified the question tags to include websphere-mq, that should improve your chances of getting an answer.  I'm not familiar with IBM's MQ product so I can't help you here, sorry.

Comment: So are you saying that you want another instance of the app that will compete for messages with the first instance?  Or are you saying that you need two different apps to consume their own copy of each message (duplicate the messages)?

Comment: We are looking to add another app to consume the same message in parallel (and not compete.). I am more familiar with TIBCO systems, in which TIBCO right out allows us to create a bridge from the original destination - in which case the TIBCO simply copies the message to the bridged destination. I am not familiar with IBM MQ much. I am just hoping it could be done using the MQ infrastructure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy with WebSphere MQ although not as straightforward as defining a bridge.

To illustrate, assume that the destination queue currently is QA such that...

```
Producer --> QA --> Consumer1
```

To do what you want, convert QA to an alias of the same name, pointing to a topic, then set up administrative subscriptions to two new endpoints:

```
(Receiver MCA) --> QA --> TopicA --> Sub1 --> QA.1 --> Consumer1
                            |
                            +------> Sub2 --> QA.2 --> Consumer2
```

You'll need to disconnect the apps that are locally attached to the queue, or shut down any RCVR/RQSTR/CLUSRCVR channel that may have it open.  But once it's converted to a topic, you can add or remove subscriptions at will without disrupting anything.

**Response to update**

Based on the response, this will be easy to do.  No need to stop the channel on the vendor side, or even coordinate with the vendor.  No need to write code on your side or change an app.

```
runmqsc MAGR1


STOP CHL(RCVRMCA) 
DEFINE QL(QA1)
DEFINE QL(QA2)
DELETE QL(QA)
DEFINE QALIAS(QA) TARGTYPE(TOPIC) TARGET(QA.TOPIC)
DEF TOPIC(QA.TOPIC) TOPICSTR(QA)
DEFINE SUB(QA1) TOPICSTR(QA) DEST(QA1)
DEFINE SUB(QA2) TOPICSTR(QA) DEST(QA2)
START CHL(RCVRMCA) 
END

C:\>AMQSPUT QA JMSDEMO
Sample AMQSPUT0 start target queue is QA
Hello world!

Sample AMQSPUT0 end

C:\>AMQSGET QA1 JMSDEMO
Sample AMQSGET0 start
message <Hello world!>
no more messages
Sample AMQSGET0 end

C:\>AMQSGET QA2 JMSDEMO
Sample AMQSGET0 start 
message <Hello world!>
no more messages
Sample AMQSGET0 end

C:\
```

Setting up the security is a bit more advanced than defining subs and topics so I'm guessing that your queue manager may need to be locked down.  Please see [*Secure Messaging Scenarios With WebSphere MQ*](http://ibm.co/UU4Nkt), and in particular the chapters on hardening your queue manager to protect administrative access and for B2B use.  Note that if the QMgr is not locked down, it is possible for anyone who has a TCP route to it to anonymously administer it and to remotely execute code on the underlying server.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob. Security wise we are already set as this is an existing setup in production. But thanks again, I will go through the link you posted.